# Adding Lat and Long to attributed table in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

i am new ArcGis 10.2 user and I have the attributed data for the land cover type (I use Raster to point tool) but it does not have the exact latitude and Longitude at the point. Could anyone please help or suggest me some idea about it? I read the website, they said I have to use the VBA script to cope with this problem, I tried but it show [image].

Comment: Use this tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000

Comment: Please add the error you get in the Geoprocessing results window,  To Open this window go to the "Geoprocesing" menu at the top of the screen and then select "Results".  You will then be able to expand the results for the current session and view the detailed results.

Comment: @Dan_h_b This one is the script.                                                                                 Dim dblX as double
Dim pPoint as IPoint
Set pPoint = [Shape]
dblX = pPoint.X

Comment: @faris can we see the error message and the code so we can help with the process? Otherwise it's a bit of a poke in the dark...

Comment: @spk578 It error show ... 999999: error executing function.  :)

Comment: @faris hmmm a general error....have you manually gone through some of the steps to make sure the data and process are correct? i.e. take a sample of the raster, convert that sample to points, and add XY locational information.

Comment: @spk578 It work .... Thank you so much for your help.... :)

Comment: @faris if the Answer below was correct please accept it as the answer...if not was it the process mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Add XY Coordinates tool on the points feature class. The tool will add two fields Point_X and Point_Y.

Be careful of:

- The coordinate system being used by the data itself as the tool add's Latitude and Longitude values as appropriate for Geographic Coordinate Systems and vs linear positions for Projected Coordinate Systems.
- The tool calculates the X and Y based on the CRS of the data source not the data frame.

[Add XY Coordinates tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000032000000)